# The Python script does not work well being an nssm service

Tags: python, windows, service, nssm

I am writing a program for remote control my pc. I use Python and NSSM to package the script into the windows service. Rn i am trying to implement remote lock.

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.LockWorkStation()

while(True):
    pass
```

I packed this code into a process. Process works, but my PC is still unlocked:( I don't got any errors or smth.
With other tasks this method works correctly. My backlight now controlled by MQTT server.

I've tryed to change Log on settings ([here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Eo9.png)), but nothing changes. But i still think that problem is here. Maybe it runs as idk "another user" who can't lock my Windows account?
I don't want to use Task Scheduler because i dont want to see console (even using pyw the console appears for a couple of milliseconds and disappears. Some libs do that).

Or is there a more convenient way to hide the console? I like the way with the service because I can easily reload my script without using the task manager.